# Rendering using the select tag on React js error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built 2 functions that return JSX content and then i made some logic to return each function once based on the user choice:

```
const Register = () =>{

const [value, setMyValue] = useState()




function Zeff(){
return(
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Zeff!</h1>
 </div>   
)
}

function Jerry(){
  return (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello Jerry!</h1>
</div>
  
)
}


const Choice = () =>{

if (value){
return <Zeff />
}else{
return <Jerry />
}
}



return(
    <div>
      <Navbar />
  <select onChange={(e)=>{setMyValue(e.target.value)}} class="form-select" aria- 
  label="Default select example">

  <option value="false">Jerry</option>
  <option value="true">Zeff</option>
  </select>

  <Choice />
  </div>
  </div>    
  )
  }
  export default Register
```

My problem is when i load the page it shows up the "Hello Jerry!" and when i choose Zeff in the select tag it also changes correctly to "Hello Zeff!" but once i go back again to Jerry it remains "Hello Zeff!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `value` is a string, so `if(value)` always returns true which is `Zeff`.

For the fix, you should have to check string matches like `if(value === "true")` instead.

*Side note that I've also moved `Zeff`, `Jerry`, and `Choice` out of `Register` for avoiding re-renderings.*

```
function Zeff() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Zeff!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Jerry() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello Jerry!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const Choice = ({ value }) => {
  if (value === "true") {
    return <Zeff />;
  } else {
    return <Jerry />;
  }
};

const Register = () => {
  const [value, setMyValue] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          setMyValue(e.target.value);
        }}
        class="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
      >
        <option value="false">Jerry</option>
        <option value="true">Zeff</option>
      </select>

      <Choice value={value} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Register;
```

Comment: Yes true my value is returning a String and all this time i thought it was returning a boolean result i changed the way you said and it worked very well except that i can't put the Choice function outside Register it says Zeff and Jerry are not defined but its fine it worked this way and ty so much

Comment: Ahhh you said Zeff and jerry and Choice all outside, Okay i will try

Answer (score 0):

you should use ( useState , useEffect ) in the right way your code will be like the below

```
const Register = () =>{

const [value, setMyValue] = useState('Jerry')
 
return(
    <div>
      <Navbar />
  <select onChange={(e)=>{setMyValue(e.target.value)}} class="form-select" aria- 
  label="Default select example">

  <option value="Jerry">Jerry</option>
  <option value="Zeff">Zeff</option>
  </select>

  <h1>Hello {value}!</h1>
  </div>
  </div>    
  )
  }
  export default Register
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is here `if (value)` is expected as a boolean value but actually the datatype here is string. So instead of doing `value === 'true'`, i will suggest you to change the option value to `zeff` or `jerry`. Also we should never do `Boolean("false")` as `Boolean("false")` will be `true`

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setMyValue] = React.useState('jerry');
  function Zeff() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Zeff!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Jerry() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Jerry!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const Choice = () => {
    if (value === 'zeff') {
      return <Zeff />;
    } else {
      return <Jerry />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <nav />
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          setMyValue(() => e.target.value);
        }}
        className="form-select"
        aria-label="Default select example"
      >
        <option value="jerry">Jerry</option> // changed here
        <option value="zeff">Zeff</option>
      </select>

      {<Choice />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: yeah i thought about that solution too

Answer (score 0):

This is a string value of true/false why you can't change the value based one the conditonally.

if you want to change perfect conditonally perfect way. try it

```
if(value === "true")
```